# GC takes too much time

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm doing some tests on Java heap with IntelliJ and I get this error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded.
```

I know this happens when GC takes too much time, but I can not understand why does GC happens so frequently and takes so much time.

**Design:**

In the main thread, I create new objects repeatly, then put them in a map. To prevent these objects collected, I will print these objects after putting all of them into the map.

In the monitor thread, I print current free heap size every time I create a new object.

**Runtime heap size configuration:**

```
-Xms5m -Xmx5m
```

**Test code:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Example {

    public static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
    public static Condition writeCondition = lock.newCondition();
    public static Condition monitorCondition = lock.newCondition();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Thread(new Monitor(lock, writeCondition, monitorCondition)).start(); // start a monitor thread
        Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int count = 0; count < 10000000; count++) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                // every time create a new Object, I will use monitor thread print current free heap size
                monitorCondition.signal();
                map.put(count, new Object());
                writeCondition.await();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
        for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
            // keep reference to these Objects, so they will not be garbage collected.
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            System.out.println(entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}

class Monitor implements Runnable {

    ReentrantLock lock;
    Condition writeCondition;
    Condition monitorCondition;

    public Monitor(ReentrantLock lock, Condition writeCondition, Condition monitorCondition) {
        this.lock = lock;
        this.writeCondition = writeCondition;
        this.monitorCondition = monitorCondition;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                writeCondition.signal();
                long heapFreeSize = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
                System.out.println(count + "  times run monitor : ");
                System.out.println("heapFreesize : " + heapFreeSize);
                System.out.println();
                count++;
                monitorCondition.await();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
60005  times run monitor :
heapFreesize:603896
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.nio.CharBuffer.wrap(CharBuffer.java:373)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:265)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
    at java.io.PrintStream.newLine(PrintStream.java:545)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:696)
    at hello.Monitor.run(Example.java:58)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: In this code you are trying to fit 10 million objects (8 bytes each, typically) into a 5Mb heap (without even counting overhead from the runtime and the rest of the elements you use). That is *not* going to work.

Comment: @gpeche Yes, in fact I expect `OutOfMemoryError`. But I can not figure out why GC takes so much time. Cause the objects I create should not be garbage collected.

Comment: Interesting read: https://plumbr.io/outofmemoryerror/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

Comment: @user6690200 Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded, which references http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When available memory gets low, the GC tries to free some memory by collecting unreachable objects in the heap. To check if an object is unreachable is not an easy task and takes some time.

When all (or most) of your objects are still referenced somewhere, this is wasted time since no memory is reclaimed. Thus, when the JVM recognizes that a substantial amount of runtime is spent running the GC instead of doing something useful, the program is terminated with an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Seems JVM is not smart enough to find all objects I create can not be garbage collected quickly, it just repeatly check these objects. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. However, the problem is inherently difficult; so it's not so much an issue of being not smart.

Comment: @user6690200 what do you mean with “JVM is not smart enough”? You are filling a map with newly created objects until the memory is full. This has nothing to do with smartness. There are no objects to collect.

Comment: @Holger I mean, does JVM spend too much time on finding unreachable objects. While in fact, there are no unreachable objects.

Comment: @Holger And, there seems still has free heap space when OutOfMemoryError thrown, I expect this error not be thrown until there is no free heap space...

Answer (score 2):

In `JVM` argument you have specified `-Xms5m -Xmx5m` so, heap size is set to `5MB` i.e. `5242880 bytes`. Now since you have executed the loop `10000000` times hence you are allocating `10000000` objects of type `Integer` and `Object` in `Map` variable `map`. Now if you look at features then you will realize that you have given `0.524288` bytes on average for a single entry in `map`. But as you know that the size of `Integer` object is more than `4 bytes`(Since size of `int` is `4 bytes` and `Integer` wraps the `int` type).

**So in short you have not allocated enough memory to `JVM` heap that's why you are getting the exception** `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded.`.

**Note**: After looking at following output from your progarm, I realized that a single entry is taking `848 bytes` of memory(see calculation below). So you will need at least `10000000 * 848 = 8480000000 bytes` i.e.  `8088 MB` of memory (either physical or virtual memory):

```
heapFreesize : 32344

4699761  times run monitor : 
heapFreesize : 31496

4699762  times run monitor : 
heapFreesize : 30648

4699763  times run monitor : 
heapFreesize : 29800

4699764  times run monitor : 
heapFreesize : 28952

4699765  times run monitor : 
heapFreesize : 28104

4699766  times run monitor : 
heapFreesize : 27256

4699767  times run monitor : 
heapFreesize : 26408

4699768  times run monitor : 
heapFreesize : 25560
...
```

Try with some more allocated heap to the `JVM` and you will not get this error. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm#PERFM161) and [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) for more info regarding `Java HotSpot VM Options`.

**Calculation:** In the provided output (posted by me above), the available memory is being printed. Now if you do calculation then you will find out that the difference between memory after adding one entry to the map is `848`. Hence I can say that, a single entry(not single Object, as there are 2 objects- Integer class and Object class) in `map` is consuming `848 byres` e.g. `32344 - 31496 = 848`; `31496 - 30648 = 848`; `30648 - 29800 = 848` and so on.

Also note that the `JVM` will increase-decrease it's heap size, as per it's need, if you have not set `-Xms` and `-Xmx` switches with the same value(as I didn't used these switches while executing the sample run).

**Note:** Your code seems **logically incorrect** because the use of `writeCondition.signal();` and `monitorCondition.await();` are not in `sync`. The program is `awaiting infinitely`. I think it is getting stuck at the end.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the loop to 60000, which is small enough to be allocated into 5MB space. I still get the same error. Is there any way I can lower the limitation on the time GC takes?

Comment: @user6690200 For `60000` entries in `map` variable, you need at least `48.6 MB` memory.  So I'd suggest to set the `JVM` parameter as `-Xms60m -Xmx60m`. _Note that 48.6 MB is the memory required by `map` to hold the entries. Some more memory will be required by `JVM` to perform it's other tasks._

Comment: Thank you very much! I found the test results may get different when using 60000 and 5MB heap size, sometimes all 60000 entry can be put into map, sometimes fails. May I ask, why do you say a single object  need `848` bytes?

Comment: @user6690200 In the provided output (posted by me in answer), the available memory is being printed. Now if you do calculation then you will find out that the difference between memory after adding one entry to the `map` is `848`. Hence I can say that, a _single entry(not single Object, as there are 2 objects- `Integer` class and `Object` class) in `map` is consuming `848 byres`_. Also note that the `JVM` will increase its heap size, if needed, if you have not set `-Xms` and `-Xmx` switches the same value(as I didn't used these switches while executing the sample run).